# Using javascript on the new widget preview / customizer page

Tags: widgets, theme-customizer

[Widget customizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-customizer/) has just become core in WordPress 3.9. I'm trying out the beta version hoping to get widgets working on the customize screen in the same way I have on the ordinary widgets page. Some of my widgets use javascript, like a select element transformed using a jQuery plugin - called tokenInput.

I need to be able to initialise the javascript on the new customizer screen where I can add / edit widgets.

- I can already initialise javascript on page load
- I can't reinitialise javascript on widget add, or on widget save.

So basically when I click on a widget to add it, or when I save it, I lose the jquery plugin and it goes back to a normal select element.

I solved this for the ordinary widgets page using something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        // -------------------------------------------
        // On page load
        // -------------------------------------------
        input.tokenInput("/search-posts.php");

        // ---------------------------------------------
        // On new widget dropped in the sort area
        // ---------------------------------------------

        jQuery(".widgets-sortables").on("sortreceive", function(event, ui) {

            setTimeout(function() { 

                jQuery("#widgets-right .select_news_post:not(.token)").each(function(){

                    var input = jQuery(this);
                    input.addClass('token');
                    select = input.next('select');

                    input.tokenInput("/search-posts.php");
                });
            }, 500)
        });

        // ---------------------------------------------
        // On widget save
        // ---------------------------------------------

        jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) {

            var widget_id_base = 'news-post';
            if (settings.data !== "undefined") {

                if (settings.data.search('action=save-widget') != - 1 && settings.data.search('id_base=' + widget_id_base) != - 1) {

                    // jQuery Tokeniser
                    jQuery("#widgets-right .select_news_post:not(.token)").each(function(){

                        var input = jQuery(this);
                        input.addClass('token');

                        input.tokenInput("/search-posts.php");
                    })
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I would use on the widget customizer page to make it reinitialise the javascript on add new widget and save widget?

Comment: This is also posted at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/initialise-javascript-on-add-save-widget?replies=3

Comment: I've taken the opportunity to fix the underlying problem in core where there is no widget-form-update event that fires when a widget's form gets replaced. Please see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27491

For how a widget would utilize the new event on both the widgets admin page and in the customizer, see https://gist.github.com/westonruter/9676069#file-customize-widgets-dynamic-fields-test-js